# Go Mod Private Repo import path (cannot find module)

Tags: go

I have this private GIT structure

```
github.com/my-company/project/webservices/service1

github.com/my-company/project/packages/stringslices
```

In the main() of the service1 package:

```
package main

import (
    slice "github.com/my-company/project/packages/stringslices"
)

func main() {
   data := []string{"a","b","c"}

    slice.SomeFunc(data)
}
```

when I try to build I get this error:

build github.com/my-company/project/webservices/service1: cannot find module for path github.com/my-company/project/packages/stringslices

My project is outside the GOPATH
Each project has a go.mod file with it

How do I resolve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have modules (go.mod, go.sum) in the root folder of ur project.

Comment: There are the go.mod/sum pair in the 'packages' folder and also in the service root folder

Answer (score 0):

might be a good idea to provide more information about your `go version` . . i have same experience as yours just a weeks ago. . i solved it with downgrading my `go version` to version `1.11.1` before i had `1.11.5` and also i check i had two `go` installed in my system `` try checking with command `which golang` `` ,, i've had the first golang in `/usr/local/go` which is my go version that i install manually and the other is from `pacman` package manager which is located in `usr/local/bin` ...

> EDIT :

Oh yea, I remember now how to solve my problem :

1. Remove `go mod` *cache*, mine was under `~/.cache` directory, i dont 
   know bout yours.
2. Try `build` your code right away, under your project directory, go 
   ahead and issue `go build`

> EDIT 2 :

i got it now, turns out nothing to do with any of my answer above, just now i stumble ( again ) with this problem,, open up your `go.mod` file and edit the first line to :

`module full/path/some/apiOfYours` to just `module apiOfYours`

Comment: I have 1.11.5 - only one version